# How to resize image without losing EXIF data?

Tags: javascript, canvas

How to resize image without losing `EXIF` data?

I use canvas to resize the image,but the resized image losed the `EXIF`. I want to get the `EXIF` data, and append this `EXIF` to the resized image? I don't know how to do it!

Comment: "canvas to resize the image" doesn't sound right. A canvas is just something you draw on. If you want to resize your canvas to something bigger than you'll have to clear and redraw your image on the canvas again ( after resizing your canvas ).

Comment: sorry,the question is not so clearly,I use canvas to draw an image,and use  canvas.toBlob to compressed the image,now I want to add the EXIF to the compressed image. My English is not so good,now,can you understand what said?Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: `canvas` doesn't seem to be the right tool. Why do you want to use `canvas` and not tools like ImageMagick?

Comment: I got it! I get the EXIF data from the original image,then use canvas to draw the image,finally,concat the EXIF data and drawed image!